# Stored procedure in firebird execute very slow

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I wrote a stored procedure in firebird server. The procedure is used on several different servers and databases. On one of them, the procedure is carried out very slowly (a few hours) where in the other servers in 3-5 seconds.Indices in each database are the same.

Do any of you encountered such a problem? We made a backup and restored a database but it did not help.

Comment: Check configuration file firebird.conf if there's a difference compared to other servers (using FileSystemCache ? Is there enough free memory)

Comment: Are the databases of comparable size, ie the number of records the SP works with is in the same order of magnitude?

Comment: You might want to recalculate the statistics of the indexes and recreate the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

When I had such a problems, it was always either corrupted database (SELECT at table with 10 records lasted few minutes) or just needed recalculation of index statistics. Try to check and fix database with gfix. If recalculating of index statistic helped, consider adding plan to your SQL statement